# Update Column values based on join with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently learning how to use CTE in SQL Server 2016, as I have some large table where I need to update some columns based on a match from a helper column, and I'm not completely sure how it's done. I know this can be done with a classic update as well, by I want to learn and understand it the CTE way right now, as it will come handy in a near future.

I have this Helper table:

```
State      ABR
Alabama    AL
Alaska     AK
Arizona    AZ
```

And I need to fill out the column State based on a join between state_short and ABR.

```
User    State_short State
John    AL          NULL
Carl    AK          NULL
Ivan    AZ          NULL
Martin  AZ          NULL
William AK          NULL
Sean    AL          NULL
Bob     AL          NULL
```

I Have tried this code:

```
WITH StateMatch AS 
(
SELECT [State] AS StateName, [ABR] FROM [States]
)
UPDATE [Users]
SET [State] = StateName
FROM StateMatch
```

But this does only give me this output:

```
User    State_short State
John    AL   Alabama
Carl    AK   Alabama
Ivan    AZ   Alabama
Martin  AZ   Alabama
William AK   Alabama
Sean    AL   Alabama
Bob     AL   Alabama
```

I can see, that I am missing a join, but I'm not sure how to with CTE - Is it done within the CTE, or in the following select clause or can it be done with a where clause? What is best and most simple solution to updating a column based on a join from another helper-table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with: you don't really need a CTE for this. You could just use a correlated subquery:

```
update Users
set State = (
    select s.State from States s where s.ABR = Users.State_short
)
where State is null
```

If you really want to use a CTE, an alternative option is to `join` within the CTE, and then update the CTE. SQLServer has amazing capabilities to backtrack things and apply the changes to the underlying table column:

```
with cte as (
    select u.State, s.State New_state
    from Users u
    inner join States s on s.ABR = u.State_short
)
update cte set State = New_state
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52d7c3e1373ede4f737039fd0b459e88)**

Answer (score 2):

To make your query work, you just need to `JOIN` `Users` to `StateMatch` on the `State_short` and `ABR` values:

```
WITH StateMatch AS 
(
SELECT [State] AS StateName, [ABR] FROM [States]
)
UPDATE [Users]
SET [State] = StateName
FROM [Users] u
JOIN [StateMatch] s ON u.[State_short] = s.[ABR]
```

You can then:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
```

Output

```
User        State_short     State
John        AL              Alabama
Carl        AK              Alaska
Ivan        AZ              Arizona
Martin      AZ              Arizona
William     AK              Alaska
Sean        AL              Alabama
Bob         AL              Alabama
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60765/1)